# Upload Multiple Files with FuelPHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, foreach, fuelphp

I currently have a script that allows me to upload 1 file to my server. It works great.

Here is a portion of the code I am using to do this:

```
        // Custom configuration for this upload
        $config = array(
            'path' => DOCROOT.DS.'foldername/tomove/your/images',
            'randomize' => true,
            'ext_whitelist' => array('img', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'),
        );

        Upload::process($config);

        // if a valid file is passed than the function will save, or if its not empty
        if (Upload::is_valid())
        {
            // save them according to the config
            Upload::save();

           //if you want to save to tha database lets grab the file name
            $value = Upload::get_files();  
            $article->filename = $value[0]['saved_as'];
         }
```

I was now wondering, **how do I loop through multiple files and upload these to my server?**

I'm guessing using a *foreach* loop but I'm a little out of my depth with this I'm afraid.

Ultimately, I plan to store these filenames in a separate table on my database.

Many thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the result in your code.

You already store it

```
$value = Upload::get_files();
```

so

```
$value = Upload::get_files();  

foreach($value as $files) {
   print_r($files); 
}
```

And you will get everything what you need

Comment: Great, Levente - good to see your face again ;-)
I may very well be back again soon - thanks

Comment: Worked perfectly. I'll now try and move each file name into a separate table - I may be back - thanks again, sir!!